# iOS - How to integrate Firebase Analytics with existing Google Analytics, GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have an existing app being tracked using Google Analytics.
I would like to add another configuration file as I would like to track the same app with a different bundle identifier.

When I try to get a new configuration file from:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/

I select my App name from the dropdown (Projects using Firebase) -> being lead to a Overview of my apps. I have added an app with the new bundle identifier.

I can select the options icon -> Manage 
Gives the possibility the download the new app GoogleService-Info.plist file.

This file has a different format from the existing GoogleService-Info.plist file (containing firebase related entries)

Using the new GoogleService-Info.plist fails during configuration in the app delegate.

Is it possible to obtain a plist file with the "old" format?
Or does Firebase Analytics have to be integrated? (Still having both screen tracking and event tracking)

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it is possible to inject TRACKING_ID as a key in the plist file. In this way then "old" configuration can find out to associate it correctly.

Then following setting the services in the plist to NO that I was not using.